# Is google earth 32 bit best for Ubuntu 64 bit 14.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, 64-bit

I want to report something amazing. Two days ago I tried to install google-earth-stable 64 bit for Ubuntu along with the required dependencies. When I tried to install it via Ubuntu Software Center I got the same old error - ia32 libs dependency. Then when I tried to switch on my Dell Vostro desktop I got a pink screen with grub options. I got nervous as it is only 2 weeks ago that I lost all my data and had to work from scratch again. I clicked the normal grub option ( do not remember what it was) and then worked away. Today morning I saw a red button and an error on top right hand screen that said partial updates. Ubuntu not only removed the google -earth software but the dependencies as well plus fixed the boot record file. That was amazing !
Anyways to my relevant question - is the 32 bit google -earth.deb file best for Ubuntu 14.04 Ubuntu ? Because with all the other dependencies being installed it still crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can install Google map 32 bit on your 64 bit machine. It will work fine. You can also install 64 bit version as well. Download and install it from [here](http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/earth/download/ge/agree.html) not from software centre of Ubuntu.

Comment: Rolen the 64 bit version did not install properly. It kept saying ia32 libs dependency. Tried all the hacks that were outlined here but none of them worked. I did download from the site you did mention.

Comment: If it doesn't install then try 32 bit version and lets see whether it installs or shows some error.

Comment: Yes thank you. I did download the 32 bit version and it did install using USC. While there are a bunch of errors that it shows while starting those are manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your systems architecture (32-64 bit), a 32 bit package will always install and run completely fine, similarly or exactly as it's 64-bit counterparts would.
In short, if you are having trouble installing 64-bit programs on 64-bit Ubuntu, then the 32-bit choice is what you should try next.